# How do I store multiple options for a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that replaces words on websites with different words.
I allow users to input their own words that they would like to be replaced, and I save these like this:

```
function storeOptions(){
var words = new Object(); // storageArea.set() method takes an object that contains all the items to be stored. This Object contains those.
$("option").each(function(key,value){ // .each(index, element)
 words[value.id] = value.text;
 chrome.storage.sync.set(words, function(){console.log("Stored: "+value.text);});
});
}
```

Before this was implemented I was successfully enabling and disabling the extension with a browseraction that used a setting stored in the same storagearea in a similar way:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"status":"enabled"});
```

The problem I am facing is that after implementing the option to add words, the status either isn't being stored properly or is affected by the options, as when I try to retrieve it it doesn't have the values "enabled" or "disabled" as shown here:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("status", function(result) {
  console.log("status: "+result["status"]); // status: status
});
```

I was thinking that perhaps I could store the words to replace as an array called in a way like:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"words" : words});
```

And I would then be able to differentiate the two by getting "status" or "words", but that did not work.

How can I store status and the words without them interfering with each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason for what you describe to happen is if there is an `<option>` element with id `status` and value `status` (in which case it would overwrite the original status).

In any case, it **is** (as you suggested) a good idea to "encapsulate" all option-related key-value pairs in an object (not necessarily an array) inside storage.

(Finally, there is no need to store the values one-by-one. It would be more efficient to first create the whole object and then store it with a single call to `chrome.storage.sync.set()`.)

```
function storeOptions() {
  const words = {};
  $('option').each((idx, element) => words[element.id] = element.text);

  chrome.storage.sync.set({words: words});
}
```

Now your storage.sync will be looking like this:

```
{
  "status": "enabled",
  "words": {
    "option_id1": "option_text1",
    "option_id2": "option_text2",
    ...
  }
}
```

You can retrieve the values like this:

```
// Retrieve the extension status:
chrome.storage.sync.get('status', items => {
  const status = items.status;
  ...
});

// Retrieve the words:
chrome.storage.sync.get('words', items => {
  const words = items.words;
  Object.keys(words).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`Replacing '${key}' with '${words[key]}'...`);
    ...
  });
});
```